# C# Memory Cache issues finding data with 13 Million rows

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, caching

I have a **WEB API (VS 2013**) project which retrives 13 Million rows in cache (HTTPRuntime.Cache).

The count for the memory object says 13M rows in cache object, but when I issue a command

```
cacheObj.OrderByDescending(o => o.ID).Where(w => w.ID == 1111111).Select(s => s).ToList();
```

it returns 0 data. I checked the Oracle DB and it shows the records. Also if I try to find another ID (for example `1234567`), I get valid data back. I have a feeling cache it may be cache size.

Any clues what might be happening? Thanks

Comment: You need to post some code for this. How and why are you certain that specific ID should be in the cache?

Comment: What's your reasoning to say there is something not working in the framework, rather than in your application or your logic? Not that it would change the result, but why would you order 13M rows, THEN filter? Why would you Select(s=>s)? If you do cacheObj.Count(), what's the result? 13M?

Comment: Why not just `cacheObj.FirstOrDefault(x => x.w.ID == 1111111).ToList()`?

Comment: My guess  is that you're not actually storing 13M objects in cache. You're probably storing a result set, that can retrieve those 13M rows.  But the problem is that once the connection to the database is closed, then you can no longer retrieve those items.  If this is what you are truly wanting (and I would not recommend it, as you can quickly exceed memory requirements)  then you need to make sure you actually retrieve all 13M rows and store them.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. Tipx, cacheObj.Count() returns 13M. Erik Erik Funkenbusch, I tried your method call and it returned NULL. What I tried now is break down the 13M into smaller caches of 500000 each and now querying each cache returns the result as expected. Also I needed to create NEW context objects for each cache or the results were still 0. Thanks again for the Help!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your comments. Tipx, cacheObj.Count() returns 13M. Erik Erik Funkenbusch, I tried your method call and it returned NULL. What I tried now is break down the 13M into smaller caches of 500000 each and now querying each cache returns the result as expected. Also I needed to create NEW context objects for each cache or the results were still 0. Thanks again for the Help!!

Comment: basically my data lies in one of the caches and I query each cache till I find the required data